# Why when using fgets() do we need to remove the string -1 when we are declaring it?

Tags: c, string, fgets

Why when we are declaring the function fgets() we need to put -1 string from the original char? like this:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main ()
{
    char string[15]; 

    fgets(string,14,stdin); // < the original variable has 15 strings, but in fgets() we need to set 14, why?
    printf("%s\n", string);

    return 0;
    getchar();
}
```

I'm a beginner in C, so i'm having this doubt in my mind

Comment: Not 15 *strings*, 15 chars. C strings are terminated with '\0' by convention, so that leaves 1 less character available.

Comment: The [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) documentation may be helpful.

Comment: Who is "we"? You have worded the post assuming the code is correct. It's more likely [cargo cult programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cargo_cult_programming) ("The term cargo cult programmer may apply when anyone inexperienced with the problem at hand copies some program code from one place to another with little understanding of how it works or whether it is required"). The -1 is not needed. Even the [fgets manual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) example doesn't have it.

Comment: You _do_ however need to check the return from `fgets` before printing `string`, like `if(fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)) puts(string);`

Comment: Well, that's no help. Now the fgets function will put at most 13 characters into your string. *IT* subtracts the 1 character for the NULL terminator, not you.

Comment: Bu Dev, "but in fgets() we need to set 14" --> No., this is incorrect.  A minus 1 is not needed.  Use `fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)`.

Comment: Please note that `sizeof string` will only work if `string` is allocated on the stack and within the current scope. If it is dynamically allocated, or passed to the current scope as a pointer, this will not work properly as `sizeof` a `char *` will be `4` or `8` depending on your system.

Comment: @Chris "sizeof string will only work if string is allocated on the stack" --> counter example: `static char string[15];`.  `sizeof string` "works" when `string` is an _array_, regardless of where it is stored.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Fair point.

Comment: @kaylum In most of the code I've seen using the fgets() function they always subtract -1 char from the variable, so I thought most did that too. But now I can understand better how it works. I'm still a beginner in C, so i'm happy to learn from my mistakes haha.

Comment: @BuDev "most of the code I've seen using the fgets() function they always subtract -1" --> Change your source of code examples.  Even better, read the spec on `fgets()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is **no need** to subtract 1 from the array length for the size argument to `fgets()`.

The second argument tells `fgets` the length of the array pointed to by the first argument so `fgets()` only writes inside the buffer boundaries.  `fgets()` will read at most one less byte from the stream than the length of the destination array and write a null terminator so make the array a C string.

Since `sizeof(char)` is `1` by definition, it is idiomatic in C to pass the size of the array as `sizeof(string)`, but only do this if `string` is an actual array, not a pointer.

Unless the stream pointer it in error or at end of file, the string read by `fgets()` will be null terminated.  You should test the return value of `fgets()` to avoid reading the array in case of failure to read a string from the stream.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    char string[15]; 

    while (fgets(string, sizeof string, stdin)) {
        printf(">>%s<<\n", string);
    }
    printf("Bye\n");
    return 0;
}
```

Now let's run the program and do some testing:

- If you type a short string `Hello!`followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, you will see 2 lines of output:

  ```
  >>Hello!
  <<
  ```

  `fgets()` read the string, including the trailing newline into the `string` array and `printf` outputs it, preceded by `>>` and followed by `<<` and a newline, producing 2 lines in one call.
- If you type a longer string `I am testing this function relentlessly` followed by the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, `fgets()` will read at most 14 bytes at a time and only the last chunk will have the trailing newline:

  ```
  >>I am testing t<<
  >>his function r<<
  >>elentlessly
  <<
  ```
- Finally, if the input does not have a trailing newline, eg: `Yes!` followed by <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd><kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd>, the array `string` will not have a newline at the end either and the next call to `fgets()` will return `NULL`:

  ```
  >>Yes!<<
  Bye!
  ```

Comment: Thank you for that!! the modified version helped a lot to understand the fgets() function now.

Comment: The poiint here is that the buffer is `NULL` terminated, but is not also "new-line" terminated  every time, so the idea of discarding the last byte as if it is always a `\n` is an error, and I think that this is what the author tried to ask for a reason

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica: good point! answer amended with a more didactic example.

Comment: @arfneto Better to use `NULL` in the context of a _null pointer_.  The character at the end of the _string_ is a _null character_ or `'\0'`.

Answer (score 4):

You *don't* need to. [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) takes three arguments.

- A C string buffer to read into.
- A count of characters.
- A file stream to read from.

It reads at most `count - 1` characters into the buffer, thus leaving room for the null terminator every C string needs.

As a side note: your call to `getchar` falls after the `return` and is thus completely pointless as control flow will never reach it.

Answer (score 0):

> Why when we are declaring the function fgets() we need to put -1 string from the original char?

I believe you are talking about the use of

```
    buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;
```

after using `fgets()` to fill in `buffer`, with the purpose of removing* the expected `\n` from the string. Not when "declaring the function" but after the call.

**Well, this is wrong**.

#### Example

```
#include <ctype.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    char      buf[5] = {0};
    const int n      = sizeof(buf);
    printf("Enter up to %d bytes: ", n);
    char* p = fgets(buf, n, stdin);
    while ((p != NULL) && (*p != '\n'))
    {
        printf("Buffer: ");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i += 1)
            if (isprint((int)*(buf + i)))
                printf("%c ", *(buf + i));
            else
                printf("0x%0X ", *(buf + i));
        printf("\n\nEnter up to %d bytes: ", n);
        p = fgets(buf, n, stdin);
    };  // while()
    return 0;
}
```

This program reads a string from `stdin` using `fgets`, buffer size is set to 5. After the read the 5 bytes are shown. When not printable they are displayed in HEX. 0x0A is the code for `\n`

#### Running

```
Enter up to 5 bytes: 12
Buffer: 1 2 0xA 0x0 0x0

Enter up to 5 bytes:
SO>
```

And there is a newline after the 12, at buf[2]

**but**

```
Enter up to 5 bytes: 1234
Buffer: 1 2 3 4 0x0

Enter up to 5 bytes:
SO>
```

Here we have no `\n` since all 4 bytes were used and the last holds the mandatory `0`, the terminating `NULL` for the string.

**And** the `'\n'` are left for the next read. The program finishes since an `ENTER` at the beginning of the string ends the loop.

Same if the user enters all 5 proposed bytes, as in

```
Enter up to 5 bytes: abcde
Buffer: a b c d 0x0

Enter up to 5 bytes: Buffer: e 0xA 0x0 d 0x0

Enter up to 5 bytes:
```

And the second call reads `"5\n"`. This time the program does not end, since the `'\n'` is on the second byte.

#### So...

`fgets()` will keep the `'\n'` at the end of the string as long as there is space for it. If all bytes are taken the remaining data is left on the input buffer.

#### `fgets` returns a pointer

As you see in the manual, `fgets()` returns a pointer to the buffer or `NULL` in case of error or end of file. In case of error `errno` is set.

If `fgets` reads nothing the buffer is not touched at all, so every day many many sudent's programs hangs because the program does not check the returned pointer and keeps using the same data over and over, after error or `EOF`.

Comment: Note: `buffer[strlen(buffer) - 1] = 0;` is UB if the first character read was a _null character_.  `buffer[strcspn(buffer, "\n")] = 0;` is a safer alternative.

Comment: "In case of error errno is set." is unclear.  The C standard library does not specify setting `errno` in any `fgets()` case.  If `NULL` is returned, code can use `feof()` to distinguish input error from end-of-file.

Comment: `isprint((int)*(buf + i))` is curious as it does not prevent UB when `*(buf + i) < 0`.  Perhaps `isprint((unsigned char)*(buf + i))`?

Comment: `*(buf + i) < 0` is not an _address_ being negative, but the `char` value retrieved from `buf + i` as negative.  `isprint(some_negative_not_EOF)` is UB.

Comment: "`errno` should be set if the thread could not access the streamhandle" is not supported by the C spec.  I suspect you are using some implementation derivative spec that specified this.